# insert multiple items into DynamoDB table using .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

I have to store at least 3 user credentials(username, password) into the DynamoDB table, but I cannot find how to create and store multiple user credentials with this code. I created just one credential using this code and my goal is to add multiple credentials into the same table that I created.
Thank you in advance.

```
public async void InsertItem()
        {
            PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest
            {
                TableName = tableName,
                Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                {
                    {"Username", new AttributeValue{S="jake@hotmail.com"} },
                    {"Password", new AttributeValue{S="1234"} }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                var response = await client.PutItemAsync(request);
                if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) MessageBox.Show("Item added successfully!");
            }
            catch (InternalServerErrorException iee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred on the server side" + iee.Message);
            }
            catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The operation tried to access a nonexistent table or index.");
            }
        }

        
        public async void GetItem()
        {
            GetItemRequest request = new GetItemRequest
            {
                TableName = tableName,
                Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                {
                    {"Username", new AttributeValue{S="jake@hotmail.com"} },
                    {"Password", new AttributeValue{S="1234"} }
                }
            };
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetItemAsync(request);
                if(response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    if (response.Item.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item(s) retrieved successfully");
                        foreach (var item in response.Item) ;
                            
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InternalServerErrorException iee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred on the server side" + iee.Message);
            }
            catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The operation tried to access a nonexistent table or index.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, if this is for a demo project it's okay but **do not store any unhashed passwords anytime, anywhere for anyone** in your database - security of user data is #1 priority.

Refer to [OWASP's Password Storage cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) for more information.

---

Change `InsertItem()` and `GetItem()` to take in 2 `string` parameters for `username` and `password`, which will allow you to reuse the method.

Also change the hardcoded username & password values in the `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` to use your parameters:

```
public async void InsertItem(string username, string password)
```

```
PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest
{
    TableName = tableName,
    Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
      { "Username", new AttributeValue { S = username } },
      { "Password", new AttributeValue { S = password } }
    }
};
...
```

Then call the `InsertItem()` multiple times with different usernames & passwords to insert multiple items.

---

If you're just adding 3 users, this is fine but if you are constantly doing batch writes to the database, take a look at the [`BatchWriteItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemCRUD.html#BatchWriteLowLevelDotNet) method which will be faster.

Comment: Yes, it is just for the demo, thanks for your answer!